# Java Swing JTree: how to change the focus on the last created node

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtree

I have a Swing Jtree in my project. I have an addNewItem method, which allow to create a new node. The question is how can I change the focus from the current element to the last created node right after the creation of a new node automatically as in the picture?

[image]

```
public void addNewItem(){
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)getTree().getLastSelectedPathComponent());
        if(node==null) return;
        Holder h_node   = (Holder) node.getUserObject();
        String key = h_node.getData().getClass().getSimpleName();
        BaseNodeAdapter adp = BaseNodeAdapter.of(key, h_node.getData());
        while(adp==null && node!=null){
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getParent();
            h_node   = (Holder) node.getUserObject();
            key = h_node.getData().getClass().getSimpleName();
            adp = BaseNodeAdapter.of(key, h_node.getData());
        }
        if(adp==null) return; // no adapter

        System.out.println("addNewItem: adapter "+adp.getClass().getSimpleName());

        String[] selectable = adp.getSelectable();
        if(selectable.length==0) return; // no selectable
        String strPath = Tools.getPath(node);
        String type = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,L("Create_a_new_item_for")+" "+key+":",strPath,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,null,selectable,null);
        if(type!=null){
            int res = adp.addItem(type);
            System.out.println("add item : "+res);
            if(res==BaseNodeAdapter.FAILED) return; // nothing
            if(res==BaseNodeAdapter.PARENT) rebuildNode((DefaultMutableTreeNode) node.getParent());
            else rebuildNode(node);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
TreePath current = new TreePath(nodeYouJustCreated.getPath());
tree.setSelectionPath( current );
```

Edit:

Just click the button to add more nodes:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class TreeInsertMRE extends JPanel
{
    private JTree tree;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int tableNumber = 20;

    public TreeInsertMRE()
    {
        super(new BorderLayout());

        //Create the nodes.
        DefaultMutableTreeNode top = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Database");
        getDatabases(top);

        tree = new JTree(top);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        add(scrollPane);

        JButton button = new JButton("Add Table to Database 1");
        add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        button.addActionListener(e ->
        {
            DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel)tree.getModel();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
            DefaultMutableTreeNode child = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)model.getChild(root, 1);

            String tableText = "Table " + tableNumber++;
            DefaultMutableTreeNode tableNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode( tableText );
            child.add(tableNode);
            model.reload(child);

            TreePath current = new TreePath(tableNode.getPath());
            tree.setSelectionPath( current );
        });
    }

    private void getDatabases(DefaultMutableTreeNode top)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            String databaseName = "Database" + i;
            DefaultMutableTreeNode databaseNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(databaseName);
            top.add(databaseNode);
            getTables(databaseName, databaseNode);
        }
    }

    private void getTables(String databaseName, DefaultMutableTreeNode databaseNode)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            String tableName = "Table" + i;
            DefaultMutableTreeNode tableNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(tableName);
            databaseNode.add(tableNode);
            getColumns(tableName, tableNode);
        }
    }

    private void getColumns(String tableName, DefaultMutableTreeNode tableNode)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            String columnName = "Column" + i;
            DefaultMutableTreeNode columnNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(columnName);
            tableNode.add(columnNode);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TreeInsertMRE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TreeInsertMRE());
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you example works, but when it comes to my implementation, unfortunately, it doesn't, and I don't understand why...